# como sacar un "em" exacto sin estar calculando

Tags: html, css

¿Cómo sacar un `em` sin estar calculando? Es decir, en `div > .p`:

```
.div {
  font-size: 30px;
}
div > .p {
  font-size: .9em;
}
```

Esto me da 27px, pero si yo quisiera 26px, como le hago para sacar ese
pixel exacto sin estar calculado hasta que lo encuentre.
¿Hay alguna formula?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien el problema, si has sacado que 0.9em es 27px con el mismo cálculo puedes sacar los 26px

Answer (score 1):

La medida `em` en CSS3 es un porcentaje del valor por defecto del nodo padre, en tu ejemplo el *hijo* hereda el valor por defecto en porcentaje.

Por ejemplo:

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
  /* equivale al doble o 200% del body */
  font-size: 2em; /* 32px */
}

p {
  /* equivale a 3/4 o 75% del valor del body */
  font-size: 0.75em; /* 12px */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Titulo</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac nibh imperdiet, gravida est at, vestibulum arcu. Nullam in consequat.</p>
  <hr />
  <!-- Este div tiene el valor por default del body, o sea 16px -->
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ac nibh imperdiet, gravida est at, vestibulum arcu. Nullam in consequat.</div>
</body>
```

---

**Conclusión**: el valor en `em`, aplicado en una formula sería algo así como `valorEnPixles / padreEnPixeles`, en tu ejemplo, `26 / 30` eso da `0.86em`.

Answer (score 0):

Es como menciona @Kleith, simplemente una regla de 3 y lo cito:

> El valor en **`em`**, aplicado en una formula sería algo así como **`valorEnPixles / padreEnPixeles`**, en tu ejemplo, **`26 / 30 eso da 0.86em`**.

Ahora debes recordar, que la idea de usar `ems`, es precisamente no estar recalculando las medidas heredadas, para que queden **"pixel perfect"** y hacer ese calculo siempre sería un tiempo perdido, sobretodo si estas todo el tiempo manipulando la medida base del contenedor padre. Sencillamente no tiene caso.

Lo que te recomiendo, sí es que no lo tienes claro todavía, es buscar ejemplos, del porque se recomienda actualmente usar "`em`" en reemplazo al `pixel` en ciertos casos y cambiar "el ship" en la forma de maquetar, porque estas pretendiendo usar una **medida dinámica** como si fuera una **medida estática** y la verdad, sí realmente necesitas usar medidas especificas, siempre será mejor usar la medida directamente en `pixeles` y no en `em`.